# WMQ MQSeries ESE jar file

Tags: java, messaging, ibm-mq

I would like to download the webshpere jar file which contains the class com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI, as my WMQ based messaging application is looking for it. I cannot find it in our company repo, maven central, in my local WMQ installation - nowhere. I have seen some mention through googling of the existence of a jar called ese.jar, but have failed to locate this. Any idea where I might find it?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the MQ CLient installed?

Comment: Which version of WMQ do you have? ESE is the MQ extended security component of MQ that has been renamed as AMS in later versions and is a chargeable component. It is included in the MQ client 7.5 onwards. Do you actually want what ESE/AMS provide?

Answer (score 0):

Archive:  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar from 7.5 upwards (use latest fix pack levels) contains that part
com/ibm/mq/ese/jmqi/ESEJMQI.class. However, that's for standalone java apps, not for use in websphere application server (RA), where it is also embedded inside wmq.jmsra.rar